# reference to a const char*, error C2664:

Tags: c++, boost

I'm looking at using boost::serialization and was trying to use a string helper given on http://www.ocoudert.com which has the interface

```
SerializeCStringHelper(char*& s) : s_(s) {}
SerializeCStringHelper(const char*& s) : s_(const_cast<char*&>(s)) {}
```

I try to use this helper in the following code (getName() returns a std::string)

```
bool MyUtilities::saveSerialLibraryToFile(const string& fileName, const MyLibrary& lib)
{
    bool saved = false;
    ofstream out(fileName, ios::app);
    if(out.is_open())
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(out);
        const char* str = lib.getName().c_str();
        SerializeCStringHelper helper(str);
//      SerializeCStringHelper helper(lib.getName().c_str());
        ar & helper;
        saved=true;
    }
    return saved;
}
```

which compiles fine, but now if i replace the const char* str and helper lines with the commented out code, i get compilation error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *&'

My question is, why is the single line, different from the two separate lines?

Answer (score 2):

`SerializeCStringHelper helper(lib.getName().c_str());`

This line attempts to pass a temporary to the constructor of `SerializeCStringHelper` the problem is you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. That is why `SerializeCStringHelper helper(str);` works, because `str` is not a temporary object.

Example:

```
#include <string>

void foo(const char*& str) {}

void bar(const char* const & str) {}

int main()
{
    std::string s("...");
    //foo(s.c_str());
    bar(s.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

This code will compile fine, because bar takes a const reference, but if you uncomment the call to foo, it will fail to compile because foo takes a non-const reference.